# JMeter, Summary report not including the time spent inside the Constant timer

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am running performance testing with concurrent users (50 threads) on a import function of the application in JMeter.

After clicked on import button, I made a call to get import status and keep looping it (using a While controller) until I receive a response with IsFinished=true.
But since I am running with 50 VU, it make 3-4 get status call every seconds and it overwhelmed the server.

So, I put a constant timer of 30 secs. It will then only made one get status call every 30 sec.

However, the wait time is not being counted toward the total time spent inside the while controller in the Summary Report.

I tested it with a single thread:
For a ~60 seconds import, it's showing 5 sec time spent in the while controller on the summary report.

How can I include the wait time in the report, so that I can get the total time spent for the import to complete?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks
Steven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxmQ1.jpg)!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use [Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) which has the option to generate parent sample for all nested elements and include duration of pre/post processors and timers in the generated sample.

Transaction controller is commonly used where it is required to measure time for test actions sequence, but it can help to implement your scenario.

Comment: Hi, 

The While Controller in my screenshot above is actually a Transaction Controller, I just named it While Controller. 
And I also has Generate Parent Sample checked. 

The problem is it's not including the Constant Timer wait time. 
Also, I have tried to use Test Action as some post suggested, but the Transaction controller is also not including the wait time in Test Action either. 

Thanks 
Steven

Comment: oh....the second option in the Transcation Controller: include duration of pre/post processors and timers 

Thanks